# Qt: List of (custom) QWidgets without performance problems

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qlistwidget, qlistview

I'm right now creating an Qt-application and have following problem:
I designed a custom QWidget with some labels and checkboxes. The application should now show a list of the custom QWidgets. I tried the QListWidget but is very slow for my use case. I want to add over 6000 elements of my custom QWidget. If I create these instances of the element and add it to the QListWidget the application will crashed.

Which is the best approach for my issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use QListView..

Comment: @Mosa you need to use `QListView`+`QStyledItemDelegate` instead of adding widgets. In delegate you can manually handle mouse/keyboard input. Ofcouse its more complex, than using widgets directly, but you need a high performance, so do it. Other (and better for you case) approach is to use QtQuick/QML or `QGraphicsScene`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, `QListWidget` or `QListView` is the way to go. Also note that you should not display custom widgets with it, try using a custom [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) instead and draw the items yourself. Depending on what you need, this can get complex really fast. I have used `QTableView` with this approach with tenth of thousands of items without performance problems.

If you really need to display custom widgets, check out a library I wrote some time ago for that exact purpose: [longscroll-qt](https://github.com/TripleWhy/longscroll-qt)
.

Comment: _`+1` for opensource solution that you did

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use with the QListView+QStyledItemDelegate-approach signals and slot and highlight feature (mouse above element) for each row each element? I used QListWidget but it was very very slow...

Comment: Qt will redraw that cell if you hover it, and you have to draw it differently. You can detect the mouse over by testing `QStyleOption::state` for `QStyle::State_MouseOver`.