# How can I add multiple QPixMap item to a widget?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qpixmap

I have video analysis c++ code and porting to the QT Creator for gui requirements.

We are detecting certain shapes and items from the video stream and adjust their size ie 100x100 and want to display on the screen. We can display through Label but only one QpixMap item.

What is the best way to show detected images automatically on a widget such as last 20 one that autosized?

Is there any a small code sample to start with it to show us the direction?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the meaning of *such as last 20 one that autosized?*?

Comment: In addition to Bearded Beaver's answer, you could of course use one Label per image, or use a QListView or a QTableView if you have to display a lot of images. See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296154/1179842) for related discussion.

Comment: the Qlabel / widget or whatevet we used should be auto size to hold the 20 images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `QWidget` and reimplement `paintEvent` to paint whatever you need using `QPainter`.

See Basic Drawing Example for details:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html